# half word is going on next line created using nsmutableattributedstring

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, nsmutablestring

Before I start, `details_Label` is `UITextView`. I have wrong naming because earlier it was label but I changed to UITextView for copy text and other functionalities.

Below is what I have

```
  details_Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[[detailsArray objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"Details"] substringToIndex:200]];

NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString;
attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", details_Label.text] attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName : [self adjustDefaultFont:85], NSLigatureAttributeName: @2}];

NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc]init] ;
[paragraphStyle setAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
[attributedString addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragraphStyle range:NSMakeRange(0, [details_Label.text length])];

details_Label.editable = NO;
details_Label.selectable = YES;
details_Label.tintColor = pBlackColor;

[details_Label sizeToFit];

[details_Label layoutIfNeeded];
[details_Label setTextContainerInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];

[details_Label.textContainer setSize:details_Label.frame.size];
details_Label.frame = CGRectMake(50*iPhoneFactorX, startX, 980*iPhoneFactorX, details_Label.frame.size.height);
```

This is how I am displaying the text.

The problem is ***half word is going in next line*** is as shown in below image...

[image]

At the start I thought it was because of long text, however when I just take first 200 characters, still problem is coming.

```
details_Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[[detailsArray objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"Details"] substringToIndex:200]];
```

***Any idea what is going wrong?***

---

### Edit 1

When I print the NSAttributedString, below is what I get.

> NSFont = " font-family: \"Arial-BoldMT\"; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; font-size: 34.72pt";
>       NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 1, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n    28L,\n    56L,\n    84L,\n    112L,\n    140L,\n    168L,\n    196L,\n    224L,\n    252L,\n    280L,\n    308L,\n    336L\n), DefaultTabInterval 0, Blocks (\n), Lists (\n), BaseWritingDirection -1, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningForTruncation NO, HeaderLevel 0";
>   }

Comment: Try this: `details_Label.numberOfLines = 0; details_Label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;`

Comment: @Mrunal : `details_Label` is `UITextView` and I tried with that too before

Comment: Then use `textContainer` property, like this : `details_Label.textContainer.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;`

Comment: @Mrunal : any idea why  this weird is happening?

Comment: with out this try once [details_Label sizeToFit];

[details_Label layoutIfNeeded];

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik : Still same :D :P

Comment: can you attach yiour project bro , i will check

Comment: oh , sorry bro,

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik : can you take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46896950/tableview-is-hanging-unresponsive-if-i-lock-and-unlock-iphone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found what was going odd...

The string I was coming is as below.

```
word1&nbsp;word2&nbsp;word3&nbsp;word4&nbsp;word5
```

However I was seeing it as

```
word1 word2 word3 word4 word5
```

As in my case `word1&nbsp;word2&nbsp;word3&nbsp;word4&nbsp;word5` is one word instead of 5 words, the text remaining text was going to next line which is default.

Hope all got the problem.

***The fix*** was I manually re-typed all text and all is working fine.

This might be happening because client copied the HTML text and pasted in text area.

### *I found this strange thing happening after doing inspect element in browser for the cPanel*

Answer (score -1):

I Suggest instead of writing it hardcoded why dont you use storyboard for alingment Step to reah for changing alignment 
1). Select your text view
2). go to attribute Inspector and choose alingment accirding to your requirement 
you could also change the color and other thing instead of hardcoding it

Comment: I used NSAttributedString for many reasons such as I want to increase height for headers and color for some text...